# Pandas gives integer from datetime index with item()

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, datetimeindex

I have 2 dataframes, taken from a larger frame (with `df.head(x)` ), both with the same index:

```
print df
                     val
DT                                                                                                      
2017-03-06 00:00:00  1.06207
2017-03-06 00:02:00  1.06180
2017-03-06 00:04:00  1.06167
2017-03-06 00:06:00  1.06141
2017-03-06 00:08:00  1.06122
...                      ...
2017-03-10 21:50:00  1.06719
2017-03-10 21:52:00  1.06719
2017-03-10 21:54:00  1.06697
2017-03-10 21:56:00  1.06713
2017-03-10 21:58:00  1.06740
```

a and b are then taken from df

```
print a.index
print b.index

DatetimeIndex(['2017-03-06 00:32:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'DT', freq=None)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-03-06 00:18:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'DT', freq=None)
```

But, when I use `a.index.item()`, I get it in the format 1488759480000000000. That means when
I go to take a slice from `df` based on `a` and `b` , I get an empty dataframe

```
>>> df[a.index.item() : b.index.item()]
Empty DataFrame
```

and further to that, when I try to convert them both:

```
df[a.index.to_pydatetime() : b.index.to_pydatetime()]

TypeError: Cannot convert input [[datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 0, 18)]] of type <type 'numpy.ndarray'> to Timestamp
```

This is infuriating, surely there should be continuity of objects when using `item()`. Can anyone  give me some pointers?

Comment: How working `df.loc[a.index.item() : b.index.item()]` ?

Comment: @jezrael TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [1488759480000000000] of <type 'long'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loc` with first value of `a` and `b`:

```
df.loc[a.index[0] : b.index[0]]
```

Your solution working if convert to `Timestamp`:

```
print (df.loc[pd.Timestamp(a.index.item()): pd.Timestamp(b.index.item())])
```